# Aerobic respiration to produce water

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Could the aerobic respiration reaction occur outside the body to produce water? If it is possible how would it occur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [net reaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_respiration#Aerobic_respiration), it is just combustion of glucose:

$$
\ce{C6H12O6 + 6O2 -> 6CO2 + 6H2O}
$$

So you could just burn a sample of glucose, and it would produce water.